Cypress - Element covered by another element after angular MDC Upgrade
I recently upgraded my angular to version 16 and with it the material also was updated. Material 16 introduced MDC and because of it my existing E2E test cases are failing.

I'm trying to type in a form field which has an input element. It was working until now with this command cy.get("#add-charger-name").type(chargerData.chargerName);. It is now being covered by the floating label.
I can make it work if I use cy.get("#add-charger-name").type(chargerData.chargerName, {force: true});. I don't want to use force assuming there is a cleaner approach.

Taking a look at the MDC docs for Floating label

The floating label is a text label displayed on top of the form field control

so you would expect that a user clicks or tabs into the field before commencing to type the text.

Method 1 - clicking the label
Before clicking the label - the label is covering the <input> element causing the test to fail.

After clicking the label - the label has moved up and the input is avaliable.

You can simulate the same in the Cypress test,
cy.visit('https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview');

cy.get('input#mat-input-5')
  .siblings('label')           // clicking on the label to make it move up
  .click()

cy.get('input#mat-input-5').type('something')
cy.get('input#mat-input-5').should('have.value', 'something')



Method 2 - tabbing into the field
Unfortunately there is no cy.tabTo() command because tabbing is a native browser feature, but cy.focus() achieves the effect.
cy.visit('https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview');

cy.get('input#mat-input-5').focus()
cy.get('input#mat-input-5').type('something')
cy.get('input#mat-input-5').should('have.value', 'something')



Thanks for the help, How do I close mat multi select ? The  normal select closes after choosing a mat-option but the multiselect doesn't work like that

It's the same as above but in reverse - click outside the element cy.get('body').click() or tab-out with blur cy.get('selector-for-multi-select').blur() or tab-in to another field cy.get('some-other-field').focus().
